# Expectation Maximization(GMM-EM) never finds the correct parameters. (Mixture of Gaussians)

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, statistics, scipy, gaussian

I am trying to learn **Expectation Maximization** for parameter estimation in Mixture of Gaussians (**1D**). However, it seems the algorithm rarely finds the right parameters. I am wondering if I am doing something wrong.

The data is generated by three gaussians at 3 different locations(`x=-10, x=5, and x=10`):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# dataset is generated with 3 gaussians at with mean at -10, 10 and 5. 
x1 = 1.0 * np.random.randn(10000) - 10.0
x2 = 1.0 * np.random.randn(10000) + 10.0
x3 = 1.0 * np.random.randn(10000) + 5.0
x = np.hstack([x1,x2,x3]) # final data set
```

I checked the histogram and x is correct. Parameter learning is done with EM updates:

```
# model and initialization
M = 3 # number of mixtures
alpha = np.ones(M)*.5 # -> likelihood of the mixture
mu = np.random.random(M)*10 # -> mean of the gaussian
sigma = np.ones(M)*1.0 # -> std of the gaussian

w_mt = np.zeros((M,len(x))) # -> q(mixture | data, parameter)

# EM
for i in range(100):
    print "alpha:", alpha, "mu:", mu, "sigma:", sigma

    # E-step
    for m in range(M):
        w_mt[m] = alpha[m] * mlab.normpdf(x,mu[m],sigma[m])
    C = np.sum(w_mt, axis=0) # normalization
    w_mt = w_mt / C

    # M-step
    alpha = np.sum(w_mt,axis=1) / len(x)
    mu = np.sum(w_mt*x,axis=1)/np.sum(w_mt,axis=1)
    sigma = np.sum(w_mt*pow(x - mu[:,np.newaxis],2),axis=1) / np.sum(w_mt,axis=1)

    sigma[sigma < 0.1] = 0.1 # avoid numerical problems
```

I would expect the algorithm to (at least sometimes) find the correct `mu`(i.e -10,5,10) with std ~= 1.0. However, it seems the algorithm is never able to do that. Any help is appreciated

**UPDATE:**

Ted Kim's fix seems to have fixed the issue. I forgot to take the square root of when calculating `std`. If anyone is interested, here is the link with the updated code: [**link**](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/keithzhou/GMM/blob/master/GMM_EM.ipynb)

Comment: If you happen to have the bandwidth, I used a lot of your code but ran into a problem. I've posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187037/cannot-get-expectation-maximization-to-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sigma is the standard deviation, but the sigma in your code is the variation (which is sigma ** 2).

try

```
sigma = np.sqrt(np.sum(w_mt*pow(x - mu[:,np.newaxis],2),axis=1) / np.sum(w_mt,axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be generalized to higher dimensions by considering the mean `mu` as vector and `Sigma` as covariance matrix instead of variance.

For example, the covariance matrix `Sigma_k` for the `k` th Gaussian can be computed in the **M-step** of **EM** with **MLE** with something like the following, where `phi[i,k]` represents the probability that the `i`th datapoint belongs to `k` th cluster, computed in the **E-step** of **EM** algorithm earlier.

`Sigma[k,:,:] = sum([phi[i,k]*np.outer(X[i,:]-mu[k,:], X[i,:]-mu[k,:]) for i in range(n)]) / n_k[k]`.

The below figure shows how the **GMM-EM** soft-clustering with `k=3` cluster centers works:

[image]

For more details, we could refer to [this](https://sandipanweb.wordpress.com/2017/03/19/hard-soft-clustering-with-k-means-weighted-k-means-and-gmm-em/?frame-nonce=3f50ed1cb9) blog post.